# What is the current state of the planed features of Ubuntu-Touch

Tags: nexus-7

I think that title explains everything. I've found this guide 
[here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Nexus7/Installation)
explaining how to install Ubuntu on Nexus 7. Cause I'm working on ad hoc connection encryption for my thesis and I haven't found any android rom/kernel implementing RSN encryption for them, before of doing "risky" procedure to install Ubuntu, I want to ask if this feature is present.

Answer (score 0):

The latest information about development is available [here](http://status.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-raring/group/topic-raring-desktop-targets-for-embedded.html). For your specific question, either the implementation is in private pages not accessible. The link above was the raring status, so it could be a bit old.